# How do you control printer tray selection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I need to display tray available for printers and after change the default selected print tray of a given printer. Does anyone have AS3 code for doing this?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible without using a Native Extension

Comment: Thanks but do you know where I could find sample about that?

Comment: for basic info on native extensions, start here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html. Post a new question in relevant section of stack exchange for getting/setting printer info from the operating system.